# Vasicek model - Bond price and volatility

Tags: volatility, bond, asset-pricing, vasicek, ornstein-uhlenbeck

Why does the bond price under the Vasicek model increase as the rate volatility increases? What is the intuition behind this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intuition is just that the bond price by definition is a convex function of the rates, and the expectation of a convex function increases with volatility. Note that this result is model independent.